# 1st form in pairing is sending 2nd form data via ajax. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

This is going to be one of those long question?

[image: Two separate forms nested in a div]

As you can see I have two forms nested in this div. When I submit either form at separate times they both go through stripe.js to receive a token which works fine other functions in the payment flow works fine. My problem is here. Below is the data sent to the server by form #credit-card, all form data is encapsulated so there should be no overflow, however, there is. Form one sends data from entire page, which leads to arrays, because some input tags have common name, my server cannot parse this information. Why is this happening?

[image]

How can I get my form to just send the data contained in itself?
This is my current javascript code running to send the form information to the server:

```
function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
  // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
  var form = document.getElementById('credit-card');
  var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
  form.appendChild(hiddenInput);
  varray=$(form).serializeArray();////serialize to objects -works-

 $.post("php/stripeApi.php",varray,function(result){


     switch (result){

         case "success":



         break
         ;
         default:
         $("#stripereturn-error").html(result);
         break
         ;




         }



     })

 }
function stripeACHTokenHandler(token) {
  // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
  var form = document.getElementById('ach');
  var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
  form.appendChild(hiddenInput);
  varray=$(form).serializeArray();////serialize to objects -works-

 $.post("php/stripeApi.php",varray,function(result){


     switch (result){

         case "success":



         break
         ;
         default:
         $("#stripereturn-error").html(result);
         break
         ;




         }



     })

 }
```

But hopefully I am  clear enough. Please no down-votes, suggestions for clarification would be nice.

Comment: Can you add your html code here?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I attached a jsfiddle here  : https://jsfiddle.net/ymum9ueg/

Comment: @CalixteSimeon The fiddle doesn't tell us what the forms do when they're submitted. Are there events attached using JavaScript? Can you include those?

Comment: I do not see that happening in the fiddle. On submit of credit-card form, it only submits parameter related to that form. Am I missing something?

Comment: @cdoshi not that I can see either. There would have to be JavaScript hooking into the "onsubmit" event on both of those forms. OP has yet to post that JS :p

Answer (score 0):

You want to be looking at the submit button and the action performed on form submission.

1. Ensure each form has its own submit button and own action.
2. If the action is a JavaScript function then make sure the selectors you're using are choosing the correct form to send to the server.

Often these issues are caused incorrect HTML mark up or a typo in JavaScript run on the submit action.

**For example, if that^ JavaScript code you've posted is the action for BOTH of those forms then you will always be posting the credit card form.**

I would say that you could make a wrapping function to submit the form after you have selected the correct form element. Something like below:

```
// Call this on the Ach form's submit action
function submitAch(){
   var form = document.getElementById('ach');
   submitFormToStripe(form);
}

// Call this on the credit card form's submit action
function submitCreditCard(){
   var form = document.getElementById('credit-card');
   submitFormToStripe(form);
}

function submitFormToStripe(form) {
   var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
   hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
   hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
   hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
   form.appendChild(hiddenInput);
   varray=$(form).serializeArray();////serialize to objects -works-

   $.post("php/stripeApi.php",varray,function(result)
}
```

[Have a look here for form documentation as well.](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)

Comment: Sadly that doesn't change the result.

Comment: @CalixteSimeon and you've checked that the functions running "onsubmit" for the forms are the correct and different functions?